# Spark DataFrame Where Clause syntax differs in Spark 2.2 vs Spark 2.3

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
    val someDF = Seq(
                (8, "bat"),
                (64, "mouse"),
                (-27, "horse")).toDF("number", "word")

someDF.select("number").where(someDF.col("word").isNull).show
```

This statement works in Spark 2.2 but fails at Run-time in Spark 2.3. Stack trace :

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) word#27 missing from number#26 in operator !Filter isnotnull(word#27).;;
!Filter isnotnull(word#27)
+- AnalysisBarrier
      +- Project [number#26]
         +- Project [_1#23 AS number#26, _2#24 AS word#27]
            +- LocalRelation [_1#23, _2#24]

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:41)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:289)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:172)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:178)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedPlan(Dataset.scala:3300)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.filter(Dataset.scala:1458)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.where(Dataset.scala:1486)
  ... 53 elided
```

To make it work in Spark 2.3 , I had to revise the statement to

```
someDF.select("number").where(col("word").isNull).show
```

I tried to look at the documentation for changes in Spark 2.3 vs 2.2 but, couldn't find anything related. Now my code is failing when pushing the jar to the cluster having Spark 2.3 version if I don't make the above change to all the places where I have used WHERE clause. Is my way of writing Where clause not a standard approach or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> Is my way of writing Where clause not a standard approach or am I missing something?

In the old versions Spark could push selection (`where`) through projection. This behavior was quite confusing as you could refer to columns that didn't exist in the `DataFrame`.

While one could argue this is a breaking change and should be properly advertised as such, it is ultimately the right approach.

So yes, you shouldn't expect this code to work and the latest release only fixed incorrect implementation.

Comment: His version that still works is just as dodgy as the one that fails, though.

Comment: Can you please elaborate @Jasper-M

Comment: I mean you are still using a column in your `where` clause which does not exist in the dataframe that gets returned by `select`. So that is still prone to failure if something in the query plan optimizer changes.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Spark 2.3.1 that was fixed for 2.3.2. [SPARK-24781](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24781)